# StringBuilder and substring performance

Tags: java, substring, stringbuilder

About a performance issue related with `String` operation in `Java`：

```
String s = ".........................,--content I wanted---,....";
```

Basically I will use `for` loop to iterate a long String and extract the contents between the `,`.

Using `substring` is to record the begin index and end index during the iteration, and then do a `s.subtring(begin,end)`.

Using `StringBuilder`, I will `append` every `char` between the comma during the iteration.

Is there a performance issue about this? I mean which one will be faster when I have a lot of such operations about `extracting` the content of a String.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `String#split` and the appen the resulting `String` values?

Comment: Just curious about the performance.

Answer (score 4):

`string.substring` is substantially faster than appending using a `StringBuilder`.

Pre Java7u6, the `substring` method returned a new `String` which kept a reference to the old string value (which is a char array), and adjusted the start and end position. Here is the constructor it called:

```
 String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
     this.value = value;
     this.offset = offset;
     this.count = count;
 }
```

This was changed, and newer versions use the following code:

```
 Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, offset+count);
```

This is still much faster, since `Arrays.copyOfRange` uses `System.arraycopy`, which copies arrays very quickly, and certainly faster than repeated calls to `append`.