# How to specify the number of alphabets (and not blank spaces) to include in a substring?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to print a substring using index value. I need to exclude the blank space while counting but it should print the output along with blank space. I want to display, say, n alphabets from the main string. The blank spaces will be as they are but the number of alphabets from the lower bound to upper bound index should be n. My code is

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String Str=new String("Welcome to the class");
        System.out.println("\nReturn value is:");
        System.out.println(Str.substring(2,9));
    }
}
```

**Output:**
lcome t

In the above mentioned code, it counts the space between the "Welcome" and "to". i need not want to count the space between them. My expected output is **lcome to**

Comment: As a note, you should almost never use `new String(String)`. Just use `str = "Welcome";`.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid counting spaces ?

Comment: what exactly you want to ask .. please be specific. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use simple mathematics. Just substring it, remove all whitespaces and compare the original length to the `String` without whitespaces. Afterwards add the difference in size to your end index for the substring.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String Str = "Welcome to the class";
    System.out.println("\nReturn value is:");
    String sub = Str.substring(2, 9);
    String wsRemoved = sub.replaceAll(" ", "");
    String wsBegginingRemoved = sub.replaceAll("^ *", "");
    String outputSub = Str.substring(2+(sub.length()-wsBegginingRemoved.length()), 9+(sub.length()-wsRemoved.length()+(sub.length() - wsBegginingRemoved.length())));
    System.out.println(outputSub);
}
```

Edit: not ignoring leading whitespaces anymore

O/P

```
lcome to
```

O/P `"My name is Earl"`

```
name is E
```

Comment: This does not work correctly! You can have some spaces in after position 9, and you will omit them. Counterexample: "My name is Earl" returns " name is " instead of " name is E".

Comment: @KevinEsche: I understand that, but if I get what OP is asking for, the expected output in this case is " name is E", to contain 7 non-whitespace characters.

Comment: @majk if it really should be 100% fitting here´s your edited answer, but i guess OP could have been able to solve it on his own based on the given suggestions here

Comment: @KevinEsche You're lucky you didn't get downvoted to oblivion like I did for making a simple mistake.

Comment: @KevinEsche: Still fails on "Your name is Earl". You simply cannot do it this way, because the end position depends also on the amount of whitespace after position 9.

Comment: @majk and why does it fail? Where in your eyes is the result wrong? Also there is no whitespace after index 9, the original output would be ` Name i`

Comment: @majk What makes you think OP wants `"Your name is Earl"`? He simply asked for `"Welcome to the class"` and that's all.

Comment: @KevinEsche: My understanding of what OP means by "not counting spaces" is that he always wants the resulting string to have 9 - 2 = 7 non-whitespace characters. The problem is that you ignore spaces in interval [2,9) and add appropriate amount of characters from [9,inf) to compensate for the whitespace, but you don't check these extra chara characters for whitespace.

Comment: @majk That's your assumption.

Comment: @gotnull: Then `return "lcome to";` would be equally valid answer, but not very useful :-)

Comment: @majk Unless you know what OP wants. It's best not to assume anything.

Comment: @majk well, i did provide an answer to how it could be done not a 100% testet and fitting answer. Based on the answer OP can continue his work to reach the result he wants to have, maybe with an recursiv continuing check for following whitespaces in the `String` or whatever he wants. But that´s unkown, since we just have a simple example the the expected output, which this answer does generate.

Comment: @majk How does `return "lcome to";` become a valid answer? He's specifically asked to substring a string that consists of `"Welcome to the class"` and have it return `"lcome to"`.

Comment: @KevinEsche: True. Apologies for sounding harsh, I just wanted to point out potential problems with the approach to make sure OP is aware. It is up to him to decide what he really wants and sees fitting.

Comment: @KevinEsche, I got ma expected logic out of it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to extract it to using a regex `^.{2}([^ ] *){7}`.

Another option is to use a simple for loop to traverse the string and calculate the end point to use for substring.

```
int non_whitespace = 0; int i;
for(i = 2; non_whitespace < 7; ++non_whitespace, ++i) { 
    while (str.charAt(i) == ' ') ++i;
}
return str.substring(2, i);
```

It is up to you which method do you consider more readable, and assess which one leads to better performance if speed is a concern.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is display **n** number of characters from the string including the spaces but **n** doesn't include the no. of blank spaces. For that, you could simply be using a loop instead of a library function.

**The Logic:** Keep displaying characters of the String str from index = 2 to index = 9-1 in a while loop. If the current character is a blank space, then increase the value of `n`, which is the upper bound of the string index for the sub string, by 1, i.e., the program will now display an extra character beyond the upper bound for each blank space encountered.

Consider the code below.

```
String str = "Welcome to the class";
int index = 2, n = 9;
while(index < n){
    char c = str.charAt(index);
    System.out.print(c);
    if(c==' ')
    n++;
    index++;
}
```

**Output:** `lcome to`
Hope you can understand this code.

---

**EDIT**
As [@Finbarr O'B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3275071/finbarr-ob) said, a check to prevent `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` would be necessary for the program for which, the loop will have to be defined as:

```
while(index < n && index < str.length()){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I'd only add a string bounds check to be sure we don't try to reference beyond the length of the string

Comment: @FinbarrO'Brien To do that, do we just define the while loop as `while(index < n && index < str.length())` ?

Comment: Yeah that's one possibility certainly. It will complete when the index references beyond the end of the string.

Comment: @progy, I understood your code. Quite simple and easy. But I asked for a code which uses substring.

Comment: @VisaaliSundaram I gave you the best thing I could come up with. Anyway, it's good that you found a correct answer to the question.

Comment: @FinbarrO'B Hey thanks for pointing out the need to put the string bounds check. That's really necessary for this algorithm to be a healthy one. I added it in the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, you can implement your own version of `substring`. The straightforward solution:

```
private static String substring(int begin, int end, String str) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    while (begin < end) {
        if (str.charAt(begin) == ' ') {
            end++;
        }
        res.append(str.charAt(begin));
        begin++;
    }
    return res.toString();
}
```

The trick here is to ignore the "count" of a space, by incrementing `end` when it's encountered, forcing the loop to make one extra iteration.

The code complexity is O(n).

---

```
System.out.println(substring(2, 9, "Welcome to the class"));
>> lcome to
```

Comment: From performance point of view, it is much better idea to not use `StringBuilder`, but use the calculated indices for one substring call to calculate the return value.

Comment: @majk I don't get it.

Comment: At the beginning do `int x = begin;`, drop the StringBuilder calls, and then do `return str.substring(begin, end);` instead.

Comment: @majk I'm not sure it has a better performance, since you're calling `substring`, which make another operations as well.

Comment: In any case, I provided the algorithm, OP can change it as he wish.

Comment: See [comment on performance substring vs StringBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755454/stringbuilder-and-substring-performance)

Answer (score -2):

You could use `replaceFirst` for this:

```
String Str = "Welcome to the class"; // remove new String()
Str = Str.replaceFirst("^ *", "");
System.out.println("\nReturn value is:");
System.out.println(Str.substring(2, 10)); // increment end index by 1
```

**Output:**

`lcome to`